# Semantic-UI Transistioning from mobile to tablet displays with the sidebar open

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

This is my html where I have a `pointing menu` when the screen width is over `630px` and a sidebar with a menu button when the screen width is less than `630px`:

```
<nav class="ui inverted sidebar menu vertical slide out" id="m_menu">
<a href="index.php" class="item">
    <i class="home icon"></i>Home
  </a>

  <a href="about.php" class="item">
    <i class="user icon"></i>User
  </a>

  <a href="portfolio.php" class="item">
    <i class="archive icon"></i> Portfolio
  </a>
</nav>

<div id="menuDiv">
  <nav class="ui inverted fluid four item pointing menu" id="menu">

    <a href="index.php" class="item">
      <i class="home icon"></i>Home
    </a>

    <a href="about.php" class="item">
      <i class="user icon"></i>User
    </a>

    <a href="portfolio.php" class="item">
      <i class="archive icon"></i> Portfolio
    </a>

    <a href="contact.php" class="item">
      <i class="message icon"></i> Contact
    </a>

  </nav>

  <div class="ui labeled icon button black" id="m_btn">
    <i class="icon list layout"></i> Menu
  </div>
</div>


<img src="http://paulandtwyla.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/table-chairs-2.jpg" alt="Table With Chairs">
```

This is my css:

```
  body{
 margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"helvetica",arial;
}

#menuDiv{
  margin:40px 40px 0 40px;
  text-align:center;
}

#menu:{
  max-width:1024px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#m_btn{display:none;}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

@media all and (max-width:630px)
{
  #menu{display:none;}
  #m_btn{
    display:inline-block;
  }
}

/*fails to fix sidebar sidebar showing @width>=631px*/
@media all and (min-width:631px)
{
    /*suggested on tutsplus,no change on applying*/
    body.pushable{margin-left:0 !important;}
    #m_menu.visible{
      display:none;  
    }
}
```

When I resize the screen to 630px or lower,the horizontal navigation bar menu disappears and a button appears in the center of the page.A link to the screenshot is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2zw0tzdhoczp4a/Screenshot%202014-12-15%2006.23.51.png?dl=0)

I open the sidebar and resize the screen to a width greater than 630px where it removes the menu items in the sidebar but not the sidebar itself.There is a screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr96c2nzvaqeejg/Screenshot%202014-12-15%2006.28.09.png?dl=0)

How can I ensure that the sidebar disappears even if open at resolutions over 630px?

## EDIT:

When the sidebar is open semantic ui wraps everything else into a `pusher` class and adds a `pushable` class to the `body`,it uses class `visible` to provide you with information about what the sidebar is doing,this is the reason for trying

```
   @media all and (min-width:631px)
  {
    /*suggested on tutsplus,no change on applying*/
    body.pushable{margin-left:0 !important;}
    #m_menu.visible{
      display:none;  
    }
  }
```

This is what the `DOM` looks like with the sidebar visible:

```
  <body class="pushable">
     <nav class="ui inverted sidebar menu vertical slide out uncover left animating visible" id="m_menu">
  <a href="index.php" class="item">
    <i class="home icon"></i>Home
  </a>

  <a href="about.php" class="item">
    <i class="user icon"></i>User
  </a>

  <a href="portfolio.php" class="item">
    <i class="archive icon"></i> Portfolio
  </a>
</nav>

<div class="pusher dimmed"><div id="menuDiv">
  <nav class="ui inverted fluid four item pointing menu" id="menu">

    <a href="index.php" class="item">
      <i class="home icon"></i>Home
    </a>

    <a href="about.php" class="item">
      <i class="user icon"></i>User
    </a>

    <a href="portfolio.php" class="item">
      <i class="archive icon"></i> Portfolio
    </a>

    <a href="contact.php" class="item">
      <i class="message icon"></i> Contact
    </a>

  </nav>

  <div class="ui labeled icon button black" id="m_btn">
    <i class="icon list layout"></i> Menu
  </div>
</div><img src="http://paulandtwyla.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/table-chairs-2.jpg" alt="Table With Chairs"></div>
</body>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9hp9Lg9/4/) and a [runnable](http://runnable.com/VI4c47A_QZhnGQXw/semantic-ui-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem that uses [`enquirejs`](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) which can be used to listen for media queries being matched and unmatched.

```
  <script src="//rawgit.com/weblinc/media-match/master/media.match.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/enquire.js/2.1.2/enquire.js"></script>

  var query='all and (min-width : 631px)';
  enquire.register(query,function(){
   $('#m_menu').sidebar('hide');
  });
```

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfkp2r51/1/) and this is a [runnable](http://runnable.com/VI4c47A_QZhnGQXw/semantic-ui-php) with this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for updating the Fiddle example, the issue appears to be that there is a conflict between the visual changes being made by the CSS and jQuery. Also, there is no code anywhere forcing the mobile menu to hide once the screen size changes back to desktop.

The solution I came up with is first to adjust the CSS to cater for the major visual changes for each `media query`, then do the same for the jQuery changes using a listener that checks for changes to the screen width.

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/p9hp9Lg9/5/)** of it in action

**CSS**

In case scripts are turned off, your CSS should always handle the basics of what you want to acheive. Otherwise, the page may break. This also has the huge benefit of less page load (never use JS when CSS can handle it).

You need to be explicit about what should happen to any mobile/non-mobile element if you change it at all using media queries. Given we're talking about something that has states: `showing/hidden`, you must specify what those states involve:

**For you mobile layout:**

```
@media all and (max-width:630px) {

/* First, hide the main menu */
    #menu {
      display:none;
    }
/* then display the mobile menu */
    #m_menu {
        display:block;
    }
/* lastly, show your mobile menu button */
    #m_btn{
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

**Desktop layout**

Basically undo everything you did for the mobile version:

```
@media all and (min-width:631px) {
/* Hide the mobile menu */
    #m_menu {
        display:none;
    }
/* Unhide the regular menu */
    #menu{
      display:block;
    }
/* Lastly, hide the mobile menu button */
    #m_btn{
       display:none;
   }    
}
```

Alternately, you could remove the media query around the desktop styles altogether, as any styles specified outside of the `(max-width:630px)` will be applied regardless once 630px is exceeded.

**jQuery**

You can then apply a listener to check for when the width changes past your chosen breakpoint. It's tricky to grab the exact width, as '630' fired too wide, so I went with 617 as it matched the `media query` breakpoints closest.

Note that this only applies to *resizing* the screen, i.e. the user drags their browser size or changes their device orientation from `portrait` to `landscape` or vica versa.

Inside the `if` statement, which will only fire if the screen resizes to desktop size, we can then forcibly hide the `#m_menu`.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
// Detect if the resized screen is mobile or desktop width
    if($(window).width() > 617) {
        console.log('desktop'); 
        $('#m_menu').sidebar('hide');
    }
    else {
       console.log('mobile');
    }
});
```

There's probably a better way of doing this last part, as `.resize()` may fire many times per second, and can slow the page noticeably.

In my experience building responsive sites, it's very useful to have a 'conditional javascript' snippet set up specifically for this sort of scenario that behaves in the same way as the `media queries`.

Comment: I have edited the fiddle to include semantic-ui and the javascript required,[here is a link](http://jsfiddle.net/p9hp9Lg9/4/)

Comment: @Timmeh Thanks for suggesting that I use `js` to accomplish the task,I used `enquirejs` to solve this problem.